# Is a compiler allowed to remove assignments to struct member if it is not obviously used?

Tags: c, standards-compliance

Consider the following code:

```
char buffer[256];

struct stX
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

void * my_memcpy ( void * destination, const void * source, size_t num );

int main()
{
    struct stX x;
    x.a = 1;
    x.b = 2;
    x.c = 3;
    my_memcpy(buffer, &x.b, 2 * sizeof(int));
    {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 2 * sizeof(int); ++i) {
            printf("%d\n", buffer[i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

A particular compiler for embedded systems decides to remove the assignments to x.a and x.c (since they are never used (at least not obviously)). Is this an optimization the c standard allows?

Of course, defining the structure instance as volatile leads in the assignment being included.

gcc and msvc do not perform this optimization (but this is not really a reasoning).

**Update:** As some answers (correctly) assumed, the compiler could optimize due to the known definition of memcpy, however, this is not what my particular implementation does. (It reserves the memory for the struct on the stack, just does not perform the assignments.) Let's assume we replaced the memcpy with a function for which the compiler has no definition available. Also, let's assume the buffer is used after the function call. I updated the sample code above accordingly.

Comment: you do realise that there's no guarantee that that memcpy would actually get you x.b and x.c? You might end up with a mouthful of padding instead.

Comment: You are right. This is not the point, though.

Comment: @Vicky: I originally thought you were right but I can think of no scenario in which there could be padding bytes.  Int is supposed to match the machine's word size.  If this aligned higher than that b (and perhaps c) fit within the alignment and thus don't get padded.

Comment: @LorenPechtel: The compiler is free to insert padding however it wants. Yes, no actual compiler should, but Vicky said "guarantee", according to the language.

Comment: @LorenPechtel: also, you can treat "int is supposed to match the machine's word size" as advice from the standard, not a hard requirement. What it actually says is that `int` "has the natural size suggested by the architecture of the execution environment". No mention of anything called a "word size", and no specific requirements in what way compiler-writers should be suggestible. In practice there are plenty of C implementations with 64 bit words and 32 bit `int`, that's not generally held to be a defect. If the CPU has 32 bit arithmetic, maybe that "suggests" a "natural" size of 32.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the compiler is free to do anything so long as the observable behaviour of the application is unaltered.<sup>*</sup>

<s>But this assumes that you have a *conforming program*, i.e. one with well-defined behaviour.  Your code doesn't exhibit well-defined behaviour; it is not valid to access `x.c` by dereferencing a pointer to `x.b` (which is what you're implicitly asking `memcpy` to do).</s>

**Update:** The paragraph above may not be correct; please see the discussion in the comments...

---

<sub>*
For a more stringent definition, see section 5.1.2.3 of the C99 standard:</sub>

> Accessing a volatile object, modifying an object, modifying a file, or calling a function
>   that does any of those operations are all *side effects*, which are changes in the state of
>   the execution environment.
>
> ...
>
> An
>   actual implementation need not evaluate part of an expression if it can deduce that its
>   value is not used and that no needed side effects are produced

Comment: I disagree. The questioner is asking `memcpy` to access `2*sizeof(int)` bytes starting from the address of `x.b`. The derivation of that `void*` passed to `memcpy` doesn't matter, what matters is that it points into the middle of an object `x` (and the start of an object, `x.b`). I think that's well-defined provided there are at least that many bytes in the complete object `x`...

Comment: ... Which there are, since `x` is POD (standard-layout) and therefore its data members necessarily occur in the order they're defined. It's up to the implementation whether `memcpy` is reading padding or `c`, but it must read something and I think that if there's no padding it *must* read `c`. So unless `sizeof(stX) > sizeof(int)*3` (which I doubt), I think the questioner's compiler doesn't conform. I may be wrong.

Comment: @SteveJessop: I was under the impression that accessing `c` through a pointer to `b` is effectively an alias, and one that the compiler is not obliged to track, hence the "optimization".  I'll peruse the standard more closely when I get some time later...

Comment: I don't think this code accesses `c` through a pointer to `b`, though. Writing `((int*)buffer)[1] = (&x.b)[1];` would be UB, I think, but that's not what `memcpy` does. For another example, I think that accessing `((stX*)((char*)(&x.b)-offsetof(stX,b)))->a` would be allowed.

Comment: @Oli: char types are allowed to alias anything. memcpy accesses chars.

Comment: @R..: I'm not sure it's not that simple, though.  We wouldn't expect `int b; int c; memcpy(buffer, &b, 2*sizeof(int))` to be well-defined, because `a` and `b` are distinct objects.  Similarly, `x.b` and `x.c` are distinct subobjects in the OP's code.  But certainly, this is a grey area in the standard, and I'm no longer convinced that my answer is correct!

Comment: They are both part of the same object (struct) and also part of the same array (representation).

Comment: @R..: Ok after some more thought, I think I agree with you.  What finally convinced me was the fact that `>`, `<` etc. are well-defined for pointers to members of a struct, so my assumption that subobjects operate under the same principles as objects was unfounded.

Answer (score 0):

GCC does quite the same optimization (using x86_64, and -O3):

```
        .file   "test.c"
        .section        .text.startup,"ax",@progbits
        .p2align 4,,15
        .globl  main
        .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB12:
        .cfi_startproc
        movl    $2, -20(%rsp)
        movl    $3, -16(%rsp)
        movq    -20(%rsp), %rax
        movq    %rax, buffer(%rip)
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
.LFE12:
        .size   main, .-main
        .comm   buffer,256,32
        .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 4.7.2 20120921 (Red Hat 4.7.2-2)"
        .section        .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

As one can read, `x.a = 1` is not executed. And it could probably be optimized further.

Comment: The difference is significant, though. gcc still writes to `c`, and the questioner's compiler doesn't. I think gcc is right and the questioner's compiler is wrong.

Comment: No, but the questioner *claims* that it removes the write to `x.c`. If that's incorrect then the question is pointless ;-)

Comment: @SteveJessop the question is not pointless as user2011348 seems to be unaware if such optimization is compatible with the C standard (which is according to other answers).

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**.The compiler can apply any optimizations on the code that assume values of variables cannot change "on their own."

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volatile_variable)

```
void bar(void) {
    foo = 0;

    while (foo != 255)
         ;
}
```

An optimizing compiler will notice that no other code can possibly change the value stored in foo, and will assume that it will remain equal to 0 at all times. The compiler will therefore replace the function body with an infinite loop similar to this:

```
void bar(void) {
    foo = 0;

    while (true)
         ;
}
```

However, foo might represent a location that can be changed by other elements of the computer system at any time, such as a hardware register of a device connected to the CPU. The above code would never detect such a change

To prevent the compiler from optimizing code as above, the **volatile** keyword is used:

```
static volatile int foo;

void bar (void) {
    foo = 0;

    while (foo != 255)
        ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of preliminary points:

- your `main` function returns `void`, which means as far as the standard is concerned your program's behavior is not defined. But let's assume that your implementation explicitly allows `void` return from `main`. Also there's no prototype in scope for `memcpy` because you didn't include `string.h`, again UB.
- the values in `buffer` are never used, so actually your whole program has no observable behavior. So the compiler is permitted to remove *any or all* of your code. One program that does nothing is just as good as another as far as the standard is concerned.

I will pretend that you wrote a program that prints `2*sizeof(int)` bytes from `buffer` after the `memcpy`:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char buffer[256];

struct stX
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

int main()
{
    struct stX x;
    x.a = 1;
    x.b = 2;
    x.c = 3;
    memcpy(buffer, &x.b, 2 * sizeof(int));
    {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 2 * sizeof(int); ++i) {
            printf("%d\n", buffer[i]);
        }
    }
    return 0; /* just in case this is C89 */
}
```

So, as I understand it, the compiler removing the assignment to `x.a` in this code is OK, but removing the assignment to `x.c` means your compiler fails to conform to the standard. Unless the struct contains bizarre padding.

*If* there were at least `sizeof(int)` bytes of padding between `b` and `c` in `struct stX` then removing the assignment to `x.c` would also be OK. The standard permits such padding, but I think I can safely guess that the actual implementation you're using doesn't have it ;-)

The explanation is that `x` has a defined state in the abstract machine, with values for `a`, `b`, and `c`. `x` also has an "object representation", which is sequence of `sizeof(stX)` bytes in memory. Your call to `memcpy` accesses `2*sizeof(int)` of those bytes, starting from the address of `x.b`. All of this is legal, and it is guaranteed that `x.b` is at least `2*sizeof(int)` bytes back from the end of the structure because C guarantees that data members of a struct are laid out in the order they're defined. So `c` must come after `b`. The only freedom the implementation has is whether it comes immediately after, or whether there is padding between them.

The compiler is allowed to "know" how `memcpy` is defined in the standard, so it can deduce that this call to `memcpy` doesn't access any of the bytes of `x.a`, since they're before `x.b`. That allows it to optimize such that those bytes in physical memory do not contain the value that they have in the abstract machine. However, it is not allowed to deduce that the call to `memcpy` doesn't access any bytes of `x.c` (unless there's that much padding in the structure), and so it is not allowed to omit copying the proper values of those bytes across to `buffer`.

If the additional bytes read beyond the end of `x.b` were padding rather than the contents of `x.c`, then of course the assignment or not to `x.c` would be irrelevant and so could be omitted.

Another legal optimization would be to transform the code to this:

```
int main() {
    ((int*)buffer)[0] = 2;
    ((int*)buffer)[1] = 3;
    ... same printf loop as before ...
}
```

that is to say, there's no requirement for `x` (or for that matter `buffer`) to "really exist" anywhere in physical memory, but the standard does require that the bytes that get printed out should be the correct bytes according to how `int` is represented in your implementation and how `struct stX` is laid out in your implementation.